# Understanding NuGet's Local Installation

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm preparing a short presentation for developers who've never used NuGet before, and I thought it might be useful to contextualize NuGet as it exists on the developers' machines. In preparing the presentation I have realized that although I can use NuGet fairly confidently, I don't know how the different pieces interact locally.

Is a copy of nuget.exe ultimately doing all nuget-y work, even if you're performing NuGet operations via the VS Package Manager Console or via the VS Package Manager UI Extension? Essentially, is the PM Console a set of PowerShell scripts wrapping nuget.exe? And is the UI Extension something which in turn wraps the PM Console? i.e.

[image: nuget wrapping]

Have I fundamentally misunderstood the relationship between the individual pieces? Am I oversimplifying?

Comment: You can start your own investigation by looking for nuget.exe on your hard drive bij executing dir /s nuget.exe in a console opened in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no official guidelines or documentations to specify wrapping relationship between those individual pieces. In General, NuGet CLI and NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio are regard as two primary tools available to help you build, publish and consume NuGet packages. The NuGet CLI is the command-line utility and supports all NuGet capabilities and the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio is a GUI tool for managing packages and it includes the **Package Manager UI** and the **Package Manager Console**.

According to the [NuGet official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/install-nuget), nuget.exe is ultimately doing all nuget-y work. If the contextualize NuGet can help you present NuGet, you can adopt it. As far as I know, the relationship you understood is feasible.

Note that:

1. There are some capabilities are supported only in the NuGet CLI:
   [image]
2. NuGet CLI and NuGet Package Manager have their own versions rather than NuGet Package Manager invoke the NuGet CLI directly. Besides, NuGet Package Manager work only within Visual Studio and NuGet CLI  can work outside of Visual Studio environment.